# Linear Layout negative margin , need one layout above another

Tags: android, android-layout, margins

i got this problem while giving negative margin [image: See this pic]

after giving negative margin i want that red part go below white part, to get shadow of categories on top of red box but as you see the redbox is coming on top

that white part is my relative layout and red part is my  custom listview

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:background="@drawable/stripe_sort"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_5"
           android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp"
 >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
        android:text="Categories"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:checked="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/sort_downarrow"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      
       android:padding="@dimen/dim_15"
        android:id="@+id/dropDown_categories"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<com.eminosoft.ebookread.util.ExpandableHeightListView   
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_12"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_12"
    
    android:background="#c03f2f" 
    android:id="@+id/ListView_Sort_categories"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:divider="@null"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
```

in this i added negative margin bottom to relative layout,  i also tried to add negative margin top to my custom list view but still same result , parent of these both layouts is a linear layout

how can i make that listview go below relativelayout?

Comment: Use relative layout.
    '<relative layout>
    <imageview/> //this will display in bottom of below image view
    <imageview/>
    <relative layout/>'

Comment: can you eloborate your answer?

Comment: add ExpandableHeightListView first and then add relative layout in your xml

Comment: the parent is linear layout so the order will change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <com.eminosoft.ebookread.util.ExpandableHeightListView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_12"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_12"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/partone"



            android:background="#c03f2f"
            android:id="@+id/ListView_Sort_categories"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:background="@drawable/stripe_sort"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_5"
            android:id="@+id/partone">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
                android:text="Categories"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:checked="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sort_downarrow"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                android:padding="@dimen/dim_15"
                android:id="@+id/dropDown_categories"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

You can try this code,basically we put your layouts inside another relative layout

Comment: ok great only 1 change, we have to write expandable list view on top, then relative layout, i will edit the answer. Thank you